# For loop and if statements in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe orange_train which has 231 variables and 50,000 observations. I want to check each variable for NA's or Zero's. If sum of NA (for factors) and Zero's(for numeric and integers) is greater than 75% of the 50,000, I want to eliminate those variables. My code is as below: But its not working as expected:

```
counting_na <- function(x) {sum(is.na(x))}
counting_zero <- function(x){length(which(x==0))}

for(i in 1:ncol(orange_train)){
  if (class(orange_train$Var[i])=='numeric' && sum(is.na(orange_train$Var[i]))< 32500) 
    {print(orange_train$Var[i])}
  else (class(orange_train$Var[i])=='integer' && [enter image description here][1]counting_zero(orange_train$Var[i]) < 32500)
  {print(orange_train$Var[i])}
```

Could someone please help me with the code. I have been struggling for a long time now and am very new to R.

my columns have headers Var1 - Var231 and the data types are numeric, factors and integers. I hope this helps

Comment: `counting_zero <- function(x) sum(x==0)`

Comment: It would be helpful if you gave a sample of what your data looks like using `dput()`. Also, you're looping over the columns in `orange_train`, but you're indexing over the rows in one variable. Perhaps you mean `orange_train[[i]]`, instead of `orange_train$Var[i]`?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [ask] give a [mcve] in your question! Copy the output of `dput(head(orange_train, 10))` in your question!

Comment: my columns have headers Var1 - Var231 and the data types are numeric, factors and integers. I hope this helps

Comment: @SindhuViswanathan, it does, but then you are still indexing them improperly. You could use `orange_train[paste0('Var', i)]` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example data

```
set.seed(10)

df <- data.frame(a = sample(c(NA, LETTERS[1]), 100, T, prob = c(.75, .25))
                 , b = sample(0:1, 100, T, prob = c(.75, .25)))
```

Calculate the percentages for each column (percent `NA` for factor, percent `0` for numeric)

```
percents <- 
  sapply(df, function(x){
    if(is.factor(x)) mean(is.na(x)) 
    else if(is.numeric(x)) mean(x == 0) 
    else NA})

percents
#    a    b 
# 0.84 0.75
```

Remove the ones greater than 75%

```
df[percents > 0.75] <- NULL

names(df)
#[1] "b"
```

You can see that the column `a` was removed, because it was a factor with 84% `NA`s

Comment: This worked like a charm! Thank you @IceCreamToucan!!! I appreciate your timely help!